# Generating Java GUI code from basic HTML/Javascript

Tags: java, javascript

I would like to know the best way and what it would require(languages/libraries) to generate Java GUI code from an HTML page with embedded Javascript code. It would emulate the HTML objects(like divs/tables) and their interactions. I don't need to emulate any complicated Javascript libraries, but just get basic functionality like handling mouse clicks/movements and key presses which Java can easily support.

I was thinking of representing all of the HTML objects using absolute positioning in Java without having to generate code for layout managers.

EDIT:
Regarding seand's comment: I meant that I don't need to convert code written in JQuery or other Javascript libraries into Java GUI code. I only want to deal with simple Javascript.

Comment: I wish you lots of luck with this one.

Comment: And here I was lamenting the problems with absolute positioning and wishing that HTML had Java-style layout managers…

Comment: I proposed an edit to your question but it was rejected by @HovercraftFullOfEels... I think you meant to say "I don't need to emulate any complicated Java libraries"? If not, please clarify, because it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Chances are slim for making this work. How about embedding the HTML into a Swing application? There's been plenty of work towards making this possible, could this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I was searching as well and it appears that nothing seems really meant to do that.

However one option is to embed a browser into your app using something like:

http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/ 
http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-browser-widget/browser.html

And then used it to load your HTML pages.